# Checking multipule answers on radio form with Array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, radio-button

I need to mark answers in a form as right or wrong.
With some help I got here, I figured out how to do so for the first question, but now i'm struggling in applying it to the other questions.
This is my code:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.wrong {width:250px ;border:1px solid #ff0000; border-style:solid; }
.right {width:250px; border:1px solid #00ff00; border-style:solid; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="office">
    <label id="ques1"> question 1</label>
        <div class="q1 q1a1"><input type="radio" name="question1"  value="q1a1" /> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 q1a2"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a2" /> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 q1a3"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a3" /> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 q1a4"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a4" /> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 2</label>
        <div class="q2 q2a1"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="q2a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q2 q2a2"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="q2a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q2 q2a3"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="q2a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q2 q2a4"><input type="radio" name="question2" value="q2a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 3</label>
        <div class="q3 q3a1"><input type="radio" name="question3" value="q3a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q3 q3a1"><input type="radio" name="question3" value="q3a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q3 q3a1"><input type="radio" name="question3" value="q3a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q3 q3a1"><input type="radio" name="question3" value="q3a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 4</label>
        <div class="q4 q4a1"><input type="radio" name="question4" value="q4a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q4 q4a2"><input type="radio" name="question4" value="q4a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q4 q4a2"><input type="radio" name="question4" value="q4a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q4 q4a4"><input type="radio" name="question4" value="q4a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 5</label>
        <div class="q5 q5a1"><input type="radio" name="question5" value="q5a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q5 q5a2"><input type="radio" name="question5" value="q5a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q5 q5a3"><input type="radio" name="question5" value="q5a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q5 q5a4"><input type="radio" name="question5" value="q5a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 6</label>
        <div class="q6 q6a1"><input type="radio" name="question6" value="q6a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q6 q6a2"><input type="radio" name="question6" value="q6a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q6 q6a3"><input type="radio" name="question6" value="q6a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q6 q6a4"><input type="radio" name="question6" value="q6a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 7</label>
        <div class="q7 q7a1"><input type="radio" name="question7" value="q7a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q7 q7a2"><input type="radio" name="question7" value="q7a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q7 q7a3"><input type="radio" name="question7" value="q7a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q7 q7a4"><input type="radio" name="question7" value="q7a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 8</label>
        <div class="q8 q8a1"><input type="radio" name="question8" value="q8a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q8 q8a2"><input type="radio" name="question8" value="q8a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q8 q8a3"><input type="radio" name="question8" value="q8a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q8 q8a4"><input type="radio" name="question8" value="q8a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 9</label>
        <div class="q9 q9a1"><input type="radio" name="question9" value="q9a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q9 q9a2"><input type="radio" name="question9" value="q9a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q9 q9a3"><input type="radio" name="question9" value="q9a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q9 q9a4"><input type="radio" name="question9" value="q9a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <label> question 10</label>
        <div class="q10 q10a1"><input type="radio" name="question10" value="q10a1"/> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q10 q10a2"><input type="radio" name="question10" value="q10a2"/> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q10 q10a3"><input type="radio" name="question10" value="q10a3"/> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q10 q10a4"><input type="radio" name="question10" value="q10a4"/> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

    <input type="button" id="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit Your   Answers" onclick="checkFunction()" />


</form>

<script type="text/javascript">


function checkFunction() {
var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div.'+checked[0].value);
console.dir(checked[0]);
if (checked[0].value === 'q1a3') {
  div[0].classList.add('right')
} else {
div[0].classList.add('wrong')
}

}; 

</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone assist?

I can't quite figure out the meaning of the [0] and how to use it next.
Also, what is the meaning of the div variable, and the 'div.' in the querySelector.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `for` loop. First add a class of `correctAnswer` to each question's correct answer. For example if the first div's correct answer is the third answer, add the code `class="correctAnswer"` after the `value` attribute.

After you've added the class to each correct answer, use the following JavaScript:

```
function checkFunction() {
    var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');

    for(i = 0; i < checked.length; i++){
        var div = document.querySelectorAll('div.'+checked[i].value);
        if (checked[i].classList.contains('correctAnswer')) {
            div[0].classList.add('right')
        } else {
            div[0].classList.add('wrong')
        }
    }
};
```

The `checked[0]` basically means that you are selecting the first element from the array of found elements. So `checked[1]` will mean you are selecting the second element,  `checked[2]` will mean you are selecting the third element, etc..

Comment: @user3185970 No problem, glad it helped. :)